# На что можно заменить вложенные forEach()?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

При работе с сложными вложенными объектами есть необходимость обойти нижний уровень:

```
const servicesIds = [];

items.forEach(item => {
    item.threads.forEach(thread => {
        thread.shifts.forEach(shift => {
            shift.services.forEach(service => {
                servicesIds.push(service._id);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Выглядит не очень.

Можно добиться того же результата без `forEach()` или `for()` или `while()`. И если да то как?

Comment: Да нормально выглядит... вот ежели тебе удастся заменить forEach на что-то иное, то как раз результат-то и получится "не очень". Или "очень не"...

Comment: `const servicesIds = [].concat(...items.map(i=>[].concat(...i.threads.map(t=>[].concat(...t.shifts.map(s=>[].concat(...s.services.map(a=>a._id))))))))` - не уверен что лучше стало :)